# How to hide objects in front of camera like in most Top down games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Most top-down games, if not all, have this mechanic: when something comes between the camera and the player, the object becomes transparent. I am also making a top-down game, and this seems very important.

I detect the objects between the player and the camera using this script (works perfectly but not efficiently, open for suggestions):

```cs
public Camera playerCamera;
public Transform playerTransform;

public float sphereCastRadius = 0.1f;
public LayerMask obstructorsLayer; // the objects that can be disabled


void Update()
{
    foreach (GameObject go in ObstructorsGOs())
    {
        if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red * new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5f);
    }

    foreach (GameObject go in NonObstructorsGOs())
    {
        if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
    }
}

List<GameObject> ObstructorsGOs()
{
    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    Vector3 rayDirection = playerCamera.transform.forward;
    float maxDistance = Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, playerCamera.transform.position);
    RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.SphereCastAll(transform.position, sphereCastRadius, rayDirection, maxDistance, obstructorsLayer);

    foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
    {
        gameObjects.Add(hit.collider.gameObject);
    }        

    return gameObjects;
}

List<GameObject> NonObstructorsGOs()
{
    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    foreach (GameObject go in FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
    {
        if (!ObstructorsGOs().Contains(go))
        {
            gameObjects.Add(go);
        }
    }

    return gameObjects;
}
```

---

I am currently changing the color of the material and multiplying it to change the alpha value. Of course, it doesn't work when the material is `Surface Type` is **Opaque**. But it also doesn't work when the material surface type is **transparent** and some other things happen which cannot be explained.

Following are the GIFs.

Opaque:

[image]

Transparent:

[image]

---

Is there any other way to achieve this?

---

This is a reference video of **something** I want to achieve.

[The Ascent](https://youtu.be/5JlcawOy72k?t=27)

---

#### Edit 1

I am using URP render pipeline.

Comment: So what's actually your problem? You say that "multiplying it to change the alpha value" doesn't work for the transparent surface type either, but the gif clearly shows that it does. The object in front of the camera becomes red and transparent.

Comment: My problem is that if the material surface type is transparent, it doesn't cast and receive shadows. @Voidsay

Comment: Make a script that goes thru all the objects with your transparent shader and do `material.SetShaderPassEnabled("ShadowCaster", true);` at the start. It will re-enable shadows.

Comment: I will try and let you know @Voidsay

Comment: @Voidsay I tried and the shadows were enabled, but some objects are rendered in front of other objects, see the GIFs for opaque and transparent. it is similar to transparent but with shadows. The objects are still rendered incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't even notice. You really need to write stuff like this in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately you've stumbled over the cursed transparency problem. When rendered the pixel depth value is omitted and the engine doesn't know what part of the model should be rendered first and then layered over. It randomly decides to render parts of the floor after the railing. For solutions you can either split up the models, so they are rendered back to front in the object queue or you could make a render pass system rendering floor, shadows, obscuring objects and adding them to the final image with transparency.

Comment: There are [tons of resources and tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+URP+shader+fade+close+objects) fo this effect .. just pick one ;)

Comment: @derHugo it worked. The link to the tutorial is in the answer if anyone else. There is also the GitHub link to the project in the video description.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmLIy62Gsnk Link to Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The standard shader rendering mode **Transparent** can't become fully invisible. If you read the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterRenderingMode.html) it says the following:

> **Transparent** - Suitable for rendering realistic transparent materials such as clear plastic or glass. In this mode, the material itself will take on transparency values (based on the texture’s alpha channel and the alpha of the tint colour), **however reflections and lighting highlights will remain visible at full clarity** as is the case with real transparent materials.

Instead you should use the mode **Fade**, since this mode will make the reflections invisible at the same rate as your other material.

Comment: It's not a standard shader, it's URP Lit Shader.

Comment: @Obscure021 should have mentioned the render pipeline in the question. Well in this case I'm not really sure how to answer, since URP lit transparent acts just like fade. You'll have to try and find words to explain what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect, what you want is a custom shader pass.

When you use a custom shader pass on your character, you can render it on top of other objects on the scene, without modifying them at all, which would be quite expensive.

For URP, Unity docs has an [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/containers/how-to-custom-effect-render-objects.html) on how to achieve what is shown on your example from "The Ascent".

[Example of shader pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUKYX.gif)

Comment: It's good, but I want to hide objects obstructing the view. Also, the problem is solved. I found a tutorial online (Link in comments of questions). But I cannot seem to remove the bounty from this question.